# On Mac OSX(Mojave)- Android emulator keeps crashing while launching

Tags: android-studio, react-native, android-emulator

Trying to launch the android emulator from android studio using avd manager but it keeps crashing. Sometimes may launch, but would crash after the debug apk is installed. I have Android Studio 3.4. The emulator also behaves very sluggish and extremely slow. How could I accelerate the emulator?

Comment: Any log message?

Comment: you could set up a new emulator with more ram.

Answer (score 0):

you have to upgrade your react native version to solve **OSX** problem

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your system details. Meanwhile, try updating all the packages and then run the emulator.